# Solving a matrix of the form $XA = cX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve a matrix of the form $XA = cX$ where $A$ is a square matrix of size $N$ with known values and $c$ is a scalar representing the largest eigenvalue of matrix $A$ (though I would think a solution would hold for any scalar). $X$ is a $1 x N$ row vector of variables. I want to solve for the values of $X$

$A$ is the infinitesimal generator for a continuous time markov chain and what I am trying to accomplish here is solving for the system of linear equations (of the form described above) that characterize the steady-state solution.

My thoughts so far:

- We can write $B$ = $A/c$ to move the scalar to the left hand side
- $XB = X$ can be written as $B'X = X$ where $B'$ is the transpose of $B$
- $B'X = X$ can be written as $(B'-I)X = 0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of size $N$

Comment: $X$ is a square matrix? We're working with matrices with real entries?

Comment: Please make your question clearer. In this equation, what is known, and what is unknown (i.e. what are we solving **for**)? What is the shape of the matrix $X$?

Comment: Also, please note that askers are expected to provide [context for their questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could answer any of the following. What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far? Where did you come across this question (or why are you asking it)?

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism. I've made some edits that hopefully clarify the question

Comment: How can $X$ be a column vector if it's on the left side of the matrix $A$ and not the right side? If $c$ is an eigenvalue, isn't $X$ just an eigenvector? What am I missing?

Comment: @CharlesMcCharles I believe you are correct that $X$ cannot be a column vector and has to be a row vector - I was mistaken and I've edited the question. Does this form suggests to you that $X$ is an eigenvector? So if eigenvalue $c$ is known, $X$ is the eigenvector that corresponds to $c$?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

$XA=cI_NX$

Where $I_N$ is the identity matrix:

$XA=X(cI_N) \Rightarrow X(A-cI_N)=0 \Rightarrow (A-cI_N)^t X^t=0 $

Since $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$($\det(A-cI_N)=\det(A-cI_N)^t=0$) and the system is homogeneous, it admits non-trivial solutions.Notice that:
$(A-cI_N)^t=(A^t-cI_N)$. So the system becomes:

$(A^t-cI_N) X^t=0 $

So $X^t$ has to be in the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $c$ of the matrix $A^t$. I think nothing more can be said(if $c$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ there aren't non-trivial solutions)